# EXSLT functions supported by FileMaker Pro

Tags: xslt, filemaker, exslt

Does anyone have a full list of EXSLT functions supported by FileMaker Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileMakerPro uses the [Xalan-C](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/) XSLT processor. The following extensions are supported:

### [EXSLT](http://exslt.org/):

**Common:**
• exsl:node-set
• exsl:object-type
**Dates and Times:**
• date:date-time
**Dynamic:**
• dyn:evaluate
**Math:**
• math:abs
• math:acos
• math:asin
• math:atan
• math:atan2
• math:constant
• math:cos
• math:exp
• math:highest
• math:log
• math:lowest
• math:max
• math:min
• math:power
• math:random
• math:sin
• math:sqrt
• math:tan
**Sets:**
• set:difference
• set:distinct
• set:has-same-node
• set:intersection
• set:leading
• set:trailing
**Strings:**
• str:align
• str:concat
• str:decode-uri
• str:encode-uri
• str:padding

### [Xalan](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/extensionslib.html):

• xalan:difference
• xalan:distinct
• xalan:evaluate
• xalan:hasSameNodes
• xalan:intersection
• xalan:nodeset

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you.